Raspberry Pi 4 Assembly Segmentation Fail
I trying to make a random number generator made using assembly. To make the file and run it I'm using vim and gcc but I keep getting a segmentation fail.
.section .data 
seed: .word OxA5A5A5A5 // Initial seed for the LFSR 
.section .text .global main 
main: 
// Start and initialization of the seed 
LDR RO, =seed // Load address of seed into RO 
LDR R1, [RO] // Load seed value into R1 
generate_random:
// Perform LFSR 
LSR R2, R1, #1 // Logical shift right 
AND R3, R1, #1 // AND with 1 to get LSB 
EOR R2, R2, R3, LSL #31 // XOR with LSB shifted to MSB 
MOV R1, R2 // Move result back to R1 
// Store new seed 
STR R1, [RO] // Store updated seed back to memory 
// Use lower bits of the seed to determine LED output 
AND R4, R1, #0xFF // Mask lower 8 bits 
BL set_leds // Branch to set_leds function 

wait_button: // Wait for button press 
LDR R5, =0xFE200000 // Base address 
ADD R6, R5, #0x34 // GPIO Pin Level Register 
LDR R6, [R6] // Load GPIO level register 
LDR R7, =0x0400 // Load constant (1 << 10) into R7 
AND R6, R6, R7 // Check GPIO pin 10 (button) 
BEQ wait_button 
// Loop until button is pressed 
// Delay loop for debouncing 
MOV R7, #0x3F0000 // Load delay value 
delay_loop: 
SUBS R7, R7, #1 // Decrement delay counter 
BNE delay_loop // Loop until delay is finished 
B generate_random // Go back to generate_random

// Function to set the LEDs 
set_leds: 
PUSH {R4-R7, LR} // Save the return address and used registers 
// Setup for the GPIO 
LDR R6, =0xFE200000 // Base address for GPIO on Raspberry Pi 4 
// Set GPIO pins 2-9 to output 
LDR R7, =0x000003FC // Load constant (0b11111111 << 2) into R7 
STR R7, [R6, #0x04] // Set as output 
// Clear the GPIO pins 
LDR R7, =0x000003FC // Load constant (Ob11111111 << 2) into R7 
STR R7, [R6, #0x28] // Clear the pins 
// Set the GPIO pins based on R4 
MOV R7, R4 
AND R7, R7, #0xFF 
LDR R8, =0x000000FC // Load constant (0b11111111 << 2) into R8 
ORR R7, R7, R8 
STR R7, [R6, #0x1C] // Set the pins 
POP {R4-R7, LR} // Restore the registers and return address 
BX LR 
// Return from function

I ran the gdb to see were its failing at set_leds and backtraces to generate_random. I have also ran a Python script to check my GPIO pins and they were good. I have also try remaking the whole file and directory and using small bits of code to try and troubleshoot it.

What environment are you running this in? Do you have direct access to memory mapped GPIO? Does it crash at the STR R7, [R6, #0x04]?

Which specific instruction is faulting, and what are the contents of all the registers at that point?
